# Work offline on a web app then upload later

Tags: offlineapps

I want my web application to be able to work offline in case there is no internet. And when its online again it should update the database. Please tell me a topic for this to research on or just give a brief idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Firebase can do this, but I have been working on an open source version for a long time. The project is called SyncIt, which does the version tracking aspect, so the changes **can** be made offline. In my GitHub there are other projects such as SyncItControl (which detects if you are connected or not using EventSource) and will upload the changes to SyncItServer (which is wrote in Node.js/MongoDB but should be easy to in other languages). There is a full demo app available in SyncItTodoMVC which is a TodoMVC project which I will be expanding into a proper service... I am beta testing the service with my wife now.

Urls are:

- https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt
- https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncItControl
- https://github.com/forbesmyester/syncit-server
- https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncItTodoMvc

Docs are highly technical for SyncIt and need a bit more user level (see bug 4) and the other projects need much more docs doing, but over the long weekend and the next few they will be expanded.